# Router problem. AngularJS on Jooma

Tags: joomla, angular

I'm trying to learn AngularJS with CiviCRM and I am doing the tutorial found [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/angular/quickstart/).
After completing the tutorial, I navigated to `http://localhost/Joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/a/about/me`, and saw this error:

[image]

When clicking on the error message link, I am redirected to this [page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/docs/error/$injector/modulerr). This page explains that the error is probably caused by `ngRoute` not being included. I went ahead and downloaded angular-route using `npm install angular-route`. There were instructions for using npm to download angular-route and use it with CiviCRM [here](https://develop.tadpole.cc/plugins/civicrm/-/tree/c4c5de9c1bb8aa244344793d11983dde7f118907/civicrm/bower_components/angular-route)

My problem is that I am not sure how to properly include `ngRoute`, or if that is even the problem. Here is what I think the relevant code is that gets produced using `civix`:

**EditCtrl.js**

[image]

**aboutme.js**

[image]

I've tried  `angular.module('aboutme', ['ngRoute']')` and `angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-route')]);` in `EditCtrl.js`. For example:

[image]

I also tried linking the `angular-route` library in the `EditCtrl.html` file like so:

[image]

I couldn't find an `index.html` file to try and add a reference to `ngRoute`.

I'd also like to note that the `aboutme.js` file produced by `civix` is completely different than the code in the tutorial. The tutorial code shows:

[image]

The produced `civix` code is already shown above.

Here is my file tree and `package.json` file:

[image]

[image]

**Any ideas on how to get this tutorial to work?**

Comment: I haven't looked at that in a while, but it's possible some changes since then have made it out of date, e.g. maybe this one although it's not about routing specifically: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20419. But depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, you might want to look at the higher-level `afform` framework, which sits on top of angular: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/afform/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The `aboutme.js` file needs to be:

```
(function(angular, $, _) {
  // Declare a list of dependencies.
  angular.module('aboutme', [
    'crmUi', 'crmUtil', 'ngRoute'
  ]);
    
})(angular, CRM.$, CRM._);
```

I also had to change the url from `civicrm/a/about/me` to `civicrm/a/#/about/me`.
I had tried the `#` earlier, but the code was still incorrect, so it didn't work.

Angular and angular-router happen to already be included in the bower components folder in `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm` , so you don't need to install angular-router with npm or otherwise.

The only other change I made is I removed the redundancy in the requires statement of `aboutme.ang.php` like so:

```
<?php
// This file declares an Angular module which can be autoloaded
// in CiviCRM. See also:
// \https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_angularModules/n
return [
  'js' => [
    'ang/aboutme.js',
    'ang/aboutme/*.js',
    'ang/aboutme/*/*.js',
  ],
  'css' => [
    'ang/aboutme.css',
  ],
  'partials' => [
    'ang/aboutme',
  ],
  // removed 'crmUi', 'crmUtil', 'ngRoute' (already in aboutme.js)
  'requires' => [
  ],
  'settings' => [],
];
```

Everything else that civix produced via the command line I left untouched.